# Google Play Pre-launch test crash - no such table: attachments

Tags: android, prelaunch

I am trying to update an app in the google play.

In the pre-launch test, it reports a crash so google play rejects my update.

But I cannot figure out where this crash occurs.

It mentions an SQLite database but it doesn't contain any DB connections and it is just an app that loads a web site on a WebViewer.

Please refer to the image for the Pre-launch report summary.

[image]

Following is the complete stacktrace

> FATAL EXCEPTION: Background tasks
> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: attachments (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT attachments._id, messages_conversation, messages_messageId, messages_partId, desiredRendition, originExtras, downloadedRendition, downloadId, status, filename, saveToSd, mimeType, automatic FROM attachments WHERE status = ?
> at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
> at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1118)
> at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:691)
> at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
> at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
> at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
> at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
> at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1436)
> at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1283)
> at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1154)
> at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1322)
> at com.google.android.gm.provider.AttachmentManager.maybeStartNextAttachmentDownload(AttachmentManager.java:964)
> at com.google.android.gm.provider.MailEngine$6.run(MailEngine.java:1304)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
> at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)

Another exception mentioned in the logcat.

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: search_sequence (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT search_sequence._id AS seqno,   CASE search_sequence.action WHEN 0 THEN 'add' WHEN 1 THEN 'del' END AS action,   'content://gmail-ls/account/' || ? || '/conversationId/' ||     search_sequence.conversationId || '/maxServerMessageId/0/labels/msg-' ||     search_sequence.messageId AS uri,   messages.dateSentMs / 1000 AS doc_score,   messages.conversation AS section_conversation,   messages.messageId AS section_message_id,   messages.fromAddress AS section_from_address,   messages.toAddresses || x'0a' || messages.ccAddresses || x'0a' ||     messages.bccAddresses AS section_to_addresses,   messages.subject AS section_subject,   CASE WHEN messages.bodyCompressed IS NULL THEN 0 || messages.body     ELSE 1 || messages.bodyCompressed END AS section_body FROM search_sequence LEFT OUTER JOIN messages ON search_sequence.messageId = messages.messageId WHERE search_sequence._id > ? AND search_sequence.type = 0 ORDER BY search_sequence._id LIMIT ?;
> 08-26 20:50:51.605: E/DatabaseUtils(11143):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
> 08-26 20:50:51.605: E/DatabaseUtils(11143):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1118)
> 08-26 20:50:51.605: E/DatabaseUtils(11143):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:691)
> 08-26 20:50:51.605: E/DatabaseUtils(11143):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
> 08-26 20:50:51.605: E/DatabaseUtils(11143):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
> 08-26 20:50:51.605: E/DatabaseUtils(11143):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
> 08-26 20:50:51.605: E/DatabaseUtils(11143):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
> 08-26 20:50:51.605: E/DatabaseUtils(11143):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1436)
> 08-26 20:50:51.605: E/DatabaseUtils(11143):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1411)
> 08-26 20:50:51.605: E/DatabaseUtils(11143):     at com.google.android.gm.provider.MailEngine.getCursorForSearch(MailEngine.java:2509)
> 08-26 20:50:51.605: E/DatabaseUtils(11143):     at com.google.android.gm.provider.MailProvider.query(MailProvider.java:295)
> 08-26 20:50:51.605: E/DatabaseUtils(11143):     at android.content.ContentProvider.query(ContentProvider.java:744)
> 08-26 20:50:51.605: E/DatabaseUtils(11143):     at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:199)
> 08-26 20:50:51.605: E/DatabaseUtils(11143):     at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:114)
> 08-26 20:50:51.605: E/DatabaseUtils(11143):     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:388)
> 08-26 20:50:51.605: E/DatabaseUtils(11143):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
> 08-26 20:50:51.605: E/Icing(8539): Cursor call threw an exception: no such table: search_sequence (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT search_sequence._id AS seqno,   CASE search_sequence.action WHEN 0 THEN 'add' WHEN 1 THEN 'del' END AS action,   'content://gmail-ls/account/' || ? || '/conversationId/' ||     search_sequence.conversationId || '/maxServerMessageId/0/labels/msg-' ||     search_sequence.messageId AS uri,   messages.dateSentMs / 1000 AS doc_score,   messages.conversation AS section_conversation,   messages.messageId AS section_message_id,   messages.fromAddress AS section_from_address,   messages.toAddresses || x'0a' || messages.ccAddresses || x'0a' ||     messages.bccAddresses AS section_to_addresses,   messages.subject AS section_subject,   CASE WHEN messages.bodyCompressed IS NULL THEN 0 || messages.body     ELSE 1 || messages.bodyCompressed END AS section_body FROM search_sequence LEFT OUTER JOIN messages ON search_sequence.messageId = messages.messageId WHERE search_sequence._id > ? AND search_sequence.type = 0 ORDER BY search_sequence._id LIMIT ?;
> 08-26 20:50:51.605: E/Icing(8539): [CONTEXT service_id=21 ]

Comment: What is the complete stack for that crash?

Comment: @spartygw sorry couldn't get your question

Comment: Your screenshot there is what's known as a stack trace showing what crashed and which function called the function that crashed...and which function called that function, etc. All the way up the call stack. What you showed is a partial stack, I want to see the whole thing.

Comment: @spartygw added the complete stacktrace

Comment: Hmm...is there another crash in the logcat for that automated test?

Comment: @spartygw yes. I have updated the question with the other exception mentioned in the logcat

Comment: I don't think that's your app that's crashing there. I think it's gmail.

Answer (score 2):

I exactly don't know the reason.

I re-run the pre-launch test with the exact same version and there was no issue reported.